# Opening a Web URL with a TCL App that is Sitting on a Network Drive

Tags: windows, url, tcl

I just finished a TCL Db App that includes a featrue to open web page URLs.  My code is as follows ($adr is the url):

eval exec [auto_execok start] \"\" [list $adr]

This code works fine on my Windows workstation.  However, after I placed the app on a network drive I receive the following error:

'\Drive\Share\Folder\Subfolder'
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.

The web page still opens, but I still get the TCl error.

Does soemone know a better way to open URLs with TCL in a server or network environment?

Thank you,

DFM

Comment: I changed my code to the following:  

catch {eval exec [auto_execok start] \"\" [list $adr]}

This seems to have eliminated the error, while opening the web page.

Answer (score 3):

The message displayed is actually being generated by CMD.EXE, the Windows command interpreter, when Tcl tries to execute the URL that you specify.  It generates that warning message to stderr when it is started with a current working directory that is set to a network path.

Two other things you could have tried:

1. run exec with -ignorestderr.  This will cause this particular warning message (and any other messages/errors written to stderr to not produce an error in Tcl).  When you wrap your code with catch, you are basically ignoring this and any other errors, which may not be ideal.

   ```
    eval exec -ignorestderr [auto_execok start] \"\" [list $adr]
   ```

   set your working directory to another path prior to the exec, which is what CMD.EXE is doing after it prints out that warning:

   ```
    cd $::env(TEMP)
    eval exec [auto_execok start] \"\" [list $adr]
   ```

Of course, be careful about running arbitrary commands and arguments that come from untrusted inputs, or someone might use your application as a backdoor to run malicious commands.

Comment: +1, and remember that last part: it's a potential source of critical security trouble otherwise.